# Reusable code at checking status respose with Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using Angular in Javascript to connect to the server, What I want to do is make reusable code.

The problem if that for each service that have to obtain data from server I have to know status response and if was 200 I have to know if the success was 1 or 0.
So... This is my code at today (using promise):

```
function obtenerUltimasOperacionesComplejo() { 
        return $http
            .get(ultimasOperacionesUrl,
                 {params: {idComplejo: 11}})
            .then(obtenerDatosUltimasOperaciones)
            .catch(generarError);
    }

    function obtenerDatosUltimasOperaciones(data) {
        var mensaje = '';
        var status = data.status;

        if(status == 401){
            mensaje = 'Acceso no autorizado.';
            return $q.reject(mensaje);
        }
        else if (status <> 200){
            mensaje = 'Ups! Hubo un problema al conectarse al servidor. Intente nuevamente.';
            return $q.reject(mensaje);
        }
        else if(status == 200){   
            var exito = data.data.success;
            if(exito == 0){
                mensaje = data.data.mensaje;
                return $q.reject(mensaje);
            }
            else if(exito == 1){
                ultimasOperaciones = data.data.ultimasOperaciones;
                return ultimasOperaciones;
            }
        }     

    }

    function generarError(e){
        var newMessage = 'XHR error! :';
        if (e.data && e.data.description) {
            newMessage = newMessage + '\n' + e.data.description;
        }
        e.data.description = newMessage;
        logger.error(newMessage);
        return $q.reject('Ups! Hubo un problema al conectarse al servidor. Intente nuevamente');
    }
```

This part of code:

```
if(status == 401){
        mensaje = 'Acceso no autorizado.';
        return $q.reject(mensaje);
    }
    else if (status <> 200){
        mensaje = 'Ups! Hubo un problema al conectarse al servidor. Intente nuevamente.';
        return $q.reject(mensaje);
    }
    else if(status == 200){   
        var exito = data.data.success;
        if(exito == 0){
            mensaje = data.data.mensaje;
            return $q.reject(mensaje);
        }
...
```

I have to use it for each service that I have...
The problem that I have is that I can't put in a function the code above, because I don't know how to set the variable with the corresponding service, I mean:

```
else if(exito == 1){
            ultimasOperaciones = data.data.ultimasOperaciones;
            return ultimasOperaciones;
        }
```

This part of code  changes for each service because "ultimasOperaciones" var is for this service in particular, for another service I have to use another variable and so on...

So... There is a way to disjoin this two part of code so I can reuse and don't have to copy and paste the most of the code?

Thanks!

Comment: You don't need to be concerned with status in the success part...only in the error part. A 401 will not go into `obtenerDatosUltimasOperaciones` it will end up in `catch`. In other words `$http` makes sure only 200 series are resolved, all else get rejected

Comment: Also the norm is to just return `response.data` and the end consumer that calls the function would know what properties to expect

Comment: Ok thanks. Are you sure that .then only response with 200 status code? So if thats true, The post is closed.

Comment: easy to check yourself...put a bad url in and run it.

Comment: I think it's technically more than 200 (e.g. 201, is also a successful result), but yes as it says on the tin "success" is just that.

Comment: @Paul right..that's why I said "200 series" since there are a few of them

Comment: Just post your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

please create a interceptor for checking every time the status of your response

http://thecodebarbarian.com/2015/01/24/angularjs-interceptors